# How to show a HTML ASP Code on a label sending from Code-Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, visual-studio-2012, webforms

I'm having a problem, which I want to send ASP HTML code to a Label from a method on Code-Behind, to make the label shows dynamically the HTML code on screen. But when I send it only works when the code Isn't `<asp:>` just HTML.

```
public void FillPage(int size)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append(string.Format(@"<asp:LinkButton ID='LinkButton1' runat='server' OnClick='LinkButton1_Click'><asp:Table ID='tableProd' class='tableProduto' runat='server'>
   <asp:TableRow>
       <asp:TableCell RowSpan='2' Width='155px'><img src='images/categorias/bebida.png' /></asp:TableCell>             
       <asp:TableCell Width='550px'>Nome</asp:TableCell>
       <asp:TableCell RowSpan='2'>Preço</asp:TableCell>
   </asp:TableRow>

    <asp:TableRow>       
       <asp:TableCell Width='550px'><div class='divTexto'><p>Descrição</p></div></asp:TableCell>             
    </asp:TableRow>          
</asp:Table>
</asp:LinkButton> "));

    lblTexto.Text = sb.ToString();                      
}
}
```

It doesn't works. But when I do the following code it works:

```
public void FillPage(int size)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append(string.Format(@"<asp:LinkButton ID='LinkButton1' runat='server' OnClick='LinkButton1_Click'><table ID='tableProd' class='tableProduto' runat='server'>
   <tr>
       <td RowSpan='2' Width='155px'><img src='images/categorias/bebida.png' /></td>             
       <td Width='550px'>Nome</td>
       <td RowSpan='2'>Preço</td>
   </tr>

    <tr>       
       <asp:TableCell Width='550px'><div class='divTexto'><p>Descrição</p></div></td>             
    </tr>          
</table>
</asp:LinkButton> "));

    lblTexto.Text = sb.ToString();                      
}
}
```

But I need the controls of LinkButton, which isn't working.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why you put table inside of linkbutton control?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.

"ASP Codes" can only be interpreted on the server. By putting them in the label, you're requiring the browser to understand them - it won't.

Comment: Again, what are you trying to accomplish? Why won't HTML elements work for you? Tells us what outcome you're trying to achieve and maybe we can tell you a good way to achieve it.

Comment: I need to make several tables (with a foreach) dynamically to be a button (LinkButton) with database information based on customer need. So I need the LinkButton worked to use your click event.

Comment: Why can't you use a Repeater, or a DataGrid? And have you heard of User controls?